# Is there any explanation for "Tequila" in the Kuragehime eyecatch?

Tags: princess-jellyfish

Kuragehime has my favorite eyecatch of all the anime I've seen:

[Kuragehime Eyecatch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu63VCPfye4)

It's very amusing, but the "tequila" is pretty irrelevant to the show. Tequila isn't in any way relevant to the plot. It seems to be just a random word that they chose to use.

Is there any explanation for why they say "tequila" in the eyecatch, or is it just a random non sequitur for comedic effect?

Comment: I always figured it was both a funny sounding word and because of the song by The Champs, which has been covered (and mocked) an absurd number of times.

Comment: @JonLin That's plausible, as kuragehime has lots of pop culture references. Unfortunately it may be difficult to find an authoritative source that confirms it, but that would answer the question completely if there is such a source.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me, but it sounds like they play [the last few beats](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H6amDbAwlY#t=2m5s) of the Tequila song backwards.

Comment: @Krazer I'm not sure if it's backwards or forwards, but they also sound similar to me.

Answer (score 7):

Although it can't really be confirmed ( or has not been confirmed yet )

> It's a reference to a song from the 70's, which was mostly instrumental but contained one single lyric repeated throughout: "tequila." I guess the style was similar enough to the miniature music bit in that eyecatch to make the reference clear to everybody old enough to get it.
>   [source1](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=279954)

Not sure which tequilla song they reffer to as there are about 20.

Comment: It's the song "[Tequila](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H6amDbAwlY)" by The Champs.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be that it probably is referencing that song, but the question is asking for an official source confirming it. Hence, I don't think I should accept this at least until the bounty period has expired. If that period does expire and no official source is found, then I'll consider accepting such an answer.

Comment: @LoganM Sounds fair enough, I will try to search for more information in the mean while.

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't seem to be any sort of official reason given for "Tequila" being in the eyecatch. I looked on every page I could find on their official website (http://kuragehime.noitamina.tv) and could not find an explanation. You'll have to translate the website into English to check.

The best explanation I can find is from http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/Kuragehime, which says that "Tequila" is [Inherently Funny Word](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InherentlyFunnyWords). According to the page:

> Fact: Whether by pronunciation, spelling, or use, some words are just plain funny to certain characters.

There are a number of websites that speculate about the reasoning but most seem to conclude that there is no reason but that it's funny. ([Example](http://www.anime-evo.net/2011/01/01/kuragehime-review/))

Comment: So, it is (supposed to be) some kind of Japanese wordplay?

Comment: From what I can tell, it's more that it's just something that they thought would sound funny.